# javascript onclick create(element) div viz popup box

Tags: javascript, events, createelement

I'm trying to make a pop up box, which gets invoked on clicking a button, this is what I've got so far.. http://jsfiddle.net/WGPhG/2/

Comment: If one of the answers below has answered your question, please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that actually does what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/WGPhG/6/

**JS**

```
function popUp(){
    var popup = document.createElement('div');
    popup.className = 'popup';
    popup.id = 'test';
    var cancel = document.createElement('div');
    cancel.className = 'cancel';
    cancel.innerHTML = 'close';
    cancel.onclick = function (e) { popup.parentNode.removeChild(popup) };
    var message = document.createElement('span');
    message.innerHTML = "This is a test message";
    popup.appendChild(message);                                    
    popup.appendChild(cancel);
    document.body.appendChild(popup);
}
```

**NOTES**

To set the class on an element you use element.className instead of element.class.
For the onclick event handler on the cancel element, it is better to directly assign the onclick handler with an anonymous function that does what you need as in my example above.

---

**EDIT (More Efficient Way)**

This is actually a much better of getting the results that you want because there is no overhead involved with recreating the elements every time the popup is shown.  Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/WGPhG/7/

**CSS**

```
.popup
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin:100px auto;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    border:2px solid grey;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
    display:none
}

.cancel
{
    display:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    height:10px;
    width:14px;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px;
    color:white;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onClick="openPopup();">click here</button>
<div id="test" class="popup">
    This is a test message
    <div class="cancel" onclick="closePopup();"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function openPopup() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
}

function closePopup() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Hello I did this and it did add to the page elements. However, popup did not show on the page do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

### Try this update on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WGPhG/1095/)

**Changed :**

1. Center page (fixed).
2. effect (fadein and fadeout)

#### HTML

```
<button onClick="openPopup();">click here</button>
<div id="test" class="popup" style="display:none;">
    This is a test message
    <div class="cancel" onclick="closePopup();"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.popup {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;  
    margin:auto;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    border:2px solid grey;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
}

.cancel {
    display:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    height:10px;
    width:14px;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px;
    color:white;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
}

.cancel:hover {
    background:rgb(255,50,50);
}
```

#### JS

```
function openPopup() {
    //document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
   $('#test').fadeIn(1000);
}

function closePopup() {
    //document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
    $('#test').fadeOut(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WGPhG/10/) and made it work.

The changed HTML...

```
 <button id="popupButton">click here</button>
```

Updated JavaScript...

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    function popUp() {
        var popup = document.createElement('div');
        popup.className = 'popup';
        popup.id = 'test';

        popup.innerHTML = "This is a test message";
        
        var cancel = document.createElement('div');
        cancel.className = 'cancel';
        cancel.onclick= function () { popup.destroy(); }
        popup.appendChild(cancel);
        
        document.body.appendChild(popup);
    }
    
    document.getElementById('popupButton').onclick = popUp;
}​
```

Did this answer your question or is there anything else?

**Update** Improved the code and the fiddle. Now open and close works

Comment: This will not work unless you have wrapped the code, document.getElementById('popupButton').onclick = popUp; in a function that gets called after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @tjscience You're right. JSFiddle handles this for you, but I added it to my answer anyway just to be complete. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Hello I did this and it did add to the page elements. However, popup did not show on the page do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function popUp(){
    var popup = document.createElement('div');
    popup.className = 'popup';
    popup.id = 'test';
    var cancel = document.createElement('div');
    cancel.className = 'cancel';
    cancel.setAttribute('onClick', 'document.getElementById("test").parentNode.removeChild('+popup +');')

    popup.innerHTML = "This is a test message";
    document.body.appendChild(popup);
    popup.appendChild(cancel);
 }
```

Comment: In your click handler code above, you do not need to re-fetch the the popup element as there is already a reference to it in scope.