# Javascripts pop-up box position

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am trying to implement a javascript pop-up box, but I am not sure how to fix the position of the pop-up window. Please check the below fiddle. When I click on the button, the box somehow appears in the middle of the page. Is there a way to make it appears right under my button?

http://jsfiddle.net/kf9mS/

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.popup{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    border:2px solid grey;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
    display:none
    }

.cancel{
    display:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    height:10px;
    width:14px;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px;
    color:white;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
    }

.cancel:hover{
    background:rgb(255,50,50);
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onClick="openPopup();">click here</button>
<div id="test" class="popup">
    This is a test message
    <div class="cancel" onclick="closePopup();"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
function openPopup() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
}

function closePopup() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
}
```

(forked from [javascript onclick create(element) div viz popup box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542822/javascript-onclick-createelement-div-viz-popup-box))

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `margin: 0 auto` property. Because It is enforcing the element to be in center.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kf9mS/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS `popup`  make `position: absolute;` and `remove top and left` property
so your `popup` would become

```
.popup{
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    border:2px solid grey;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
    display:none
    }
```

Rest all is fine