# Change every time the content of a javascript, in a "while"?

Tags: javascript, testing, popup

I need help with some javascripts.
I am using this --> [javascript onclick create(element) div viz popup box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542822/javascript-onclick-createelement-div-viz-popup-box)
and i use it in a **php page**, inside a while.
The problem is when i use

```
<div id="test" class="popup">
```

because everytime of cause i make it print "test" to my javascript.

```
    function openPopup() 
{
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
}
```

and it takes always the first line i make it print, and it forgets of all the others.
How can i use something to make each line different from the others?

Comment: share your code in jsfiddle

Comment: What simplecoder said, plus making sure that it replicates the error you're seeing.